# Why don't I get notifications in HMS if I disable and re-enable them?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-push-notification

Using `"@hmscore/react-native-hms-push": "6.11.0-300"`, I have a utility in my app that opens notification settings, and user can enable/disable them.

The problem is that if

1. a user has disabled notifications
2. is sent a notification that is blocked
3. then later re-enables notification

they still don't get notifications even though they should. If they weren't sent any blocked notification in step 2, the notifications work as normal.

If I follow an arcane set of reloads and restarts (not sure which ones work, and it seems random), the notifications are eventually enabled.

So is there a step I am missing that would enable the HMS notifications immediately after the permission is granted? I tried all combinations of manually triggering `HmsPushMessaging.turnOnPush()`, `notifee.requestPermission()` and `HmsPushInstanceId.getToken('HCM')` but no dice. Any idea what's this all about, and how it can be fixed?